# (Python) How to design a passband filter from a graph

Tags: python, filter

I was wondering if someone would be able to explain how to design a passband filter (Butterworth specifically) for an ECG given a lead plot for the ECG.  The current code that I'm working with is as followed:

[screenshot of how the published code looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPoMA.png)

And I was wondering how I would be able to reproduce the same data with a passband filter applied, along with how to adjust the sampling rate.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

```
import scipy.io as sio
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from os.path import dirname, join as pjoin
mat_fname = pjoin('A00X.mat')
# based on the assigned list for the class, choose the number of your own patient here.
patient_number = X
# it seems lead 9 (as a single channel) is easier to analyze
ECG_lead = 9
# load the "mat" file into our Python
datapass = './Data'
if patient_number < 10:
    patient_name = 'A000' + str(patient_number)
else:
    patient_name = 'A00' + str(patient_number)
filename = patient_name + '.mat'
mat_fname = pjoin('A00X.mat')
mat_contents = sio.loadmat(mat_fname)
val = mat_contents['val']
# these are the names of ECG leads 
ECG_lead_names = ['I','II','III','aVR','aVL','aVF','V1','V2','V3','V4','V5','V6']
# plot your ECG for the first 2000 points (samples)
plt.plot(val[ECG_lead][0:2000])
plt.title('Patient X ECG')
plt.xlabel('Samples')
plt.ylabel('mv')
#plt.ylim([-200,200])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into your question, it makes it a lot easier for people to use your code and improve it from there :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @TerryA, alright, code was edited into the original post